# Разбиение (секционирование) в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

В общем, есть база на 29 млн строк. В нее идет постоянная запись, и из нее нужно тоже постоянно получать данные.

Партицирование, вроде, выход, но что пример не вижу, так больше сомневаюсь.
Есть пример - создание таблицы каждый день, другой по чеку предлагает в разные таблицы писать,
а мне вот нужно что - существующую таблицу рабить по месяцам и создать новую таблицу с данными за последнюю неделю, то бишь будет нахлест из данных в текущей таблице и данных за текущий месяц.

Comment: почитайте http://postgresql.leopard.in.ua/html/#%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
в этой книге хорошо описано партиционирование

Answer (score 1):

CREATE INDEX